# How to open a file with a determined application even when the type is opened by default by another application?

Tags: filemanager, file-format, mime-type

**Context**
Okular is a PDF reader with support to annotations, bookmarks, etc. When I want to save the PDF with the annotations and bookmarks embedded, Okular saves a `application/zip` file.
When I open that file with Okular, it opens like a normal PDF, but with the annotations and bookmarks, like expected.

**Problem**
Since the `application/zip` is not exclusive to Okular, I can't define it to always open with Okular.

**Possible solution**
Define the default application of a file to open accordingly to it's extension. For example, if the type type is `application/zip` and have the `.okular` extension, open with Okular. Else, open with Archive Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Open Nautilus and find a ".okular" file. Right click the file and select "Properties"
Click the "Open With" Tab and select the Okular Application. Click the "Set As Default" button.

Comment: That does not resolve the problem.